# my user with limited permissions setup do not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Sql Server 2019
I want to create a user with limited privileges, that user have permission only to SELECT on one database tables, I will have 4 different users with same privileges on one(same) database
When I create everything, login, db user for this login, grant select to user,
and log in as that new user in SSMS, when I click on the database where there is no user for my login popup tells me that I have no privileges and I don't see any tables
If I click on the database I have select rights for, I see tables, I can select, but I can also alter, exec, update, insert, everything....
if I write query 'USE anotherDatabase', I can, and then I can select, insert, everything on those other database tables, although I am not a user on that other database
i can also exec
`SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE xtype = 'U' GO`
on any database
Do I have to setup the server differently so that I can create user that can only SELECT on one database

Any help

I tried creating roles, addrolemember, deny, revoke, everything i colud find as a solution

Comment: have you check under securoty which roles the new user has? and which rights those actually have

Comment: yes, i have checked, and everything is as it should be

Comment: Did you actually login with the "luser" user and not your own super admin

Comment: In SSMS, you can script the login you created and compare it with other logins that "work"

Comment: yes, I've logged as the user, that's how i found out that i have an issue because when i execute as user everything works fine

Comment: Can you paste the output of the scripted login from ssms with relevant info? It should display which role it has etc

Comment: there is nothing to output, login is user in a db, and if i log in with this user without any privileges, i can select * from sys.databases, use any db, create tables, delete,.... but as admin i can not deny this user in any db except the one he is user in and that does not work